# Check box styling - How to?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How would I style a checkbox eg. Give it a background that I made in photoshop and style the tick image as one that I again made in photoshop?
Thanks.

Comment: [First result on Google](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/), don't turn to Stackoverflow without trying yourself first.

Comment: Hi MW3 Fan! Welcome to Stackoverflow! I would like to remind you that it is always an option to Google your question and get an answer from there; you might even find the answer on a past thread! Please keep this in mind, and good luck!

Comment: Okay, I did google around for some answers, but I'm guessing that my keywords were a bit off. Thank you nmagerko, I feel very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the help of some jQuery plugins as it's not possible with pure CSS right now.

Look at [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/radiobutton-checkbox-replacement) for example, [this one too](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, I especially like the jQuery method but thank you to everyone else for your also helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [nice little tutorial](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) for checkboxes, radio buttons and list boxes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy and may be not possible to correctly style a checkbox in all browsers, your best bet is to use javascript and css together to create an effect which will give the same end result e.g. here is a script which does that http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/ or more here http://line25.com/articles/jquery-plugins-for-styling-checkbox-radio-buttons

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic example, but you should be able to build upon it using a bit of design and get something looking good and working well.

http://jsfiddle.net/will/Kv67W/